# android listview last visible line

Tags: android, listview

In my application, i've a list view, if the last visible line is truncated and I scroll down to this line, I wish that the line becomes fully visible. I have to scroll down once more for it to become fully visible.

Comment: The last row is truncated? That is abnormal.. do you have any code you can post? Note: you should *edit* the original question above instead of posting answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found!
My list is not very high but his lines are quite high. So I overloaded getMaxScrollAmount method which by default is limited to one third of the total height of the list.

Answer (score 0):

May be requestChildRectangleOnScreen can help. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Comment: I can not find when and how to use it.